# How can I do a switch statement in BigQuery without an aggregation error?

Tags: google-bigquery, case

In BigQuery I have a table that has a weekly running average of values in the column wkly_ul_pc and wkly_dl_pc. I want to nullify values that appear in the first week. I can't use an `order by` and count row numbers, as there are multiple timeseries. Instead I check the date itself. Here is the relevant part of my query:

```
SELECT
    QOSdate,
    ID,
    CASE
       WHEN QOSdate > 6 + MIN(QOSdate)
          THEN wkly_ul_pc
       ELSE NULL
    END AS wkly_ul_pc,
    CASE
       WHEN QOSdate > 6 + MIN(QOSdate)
          THEN wkly_dl_pc
       ELSE NULL
    END AS wkly_dl_pc
FROM 
    running_avg
```

But I get this error:

> SELECT list expression references column QOSdate which is neither grouped nor aggregated

I've seen responses to this error where the data was grouped using a `group by` and the variables attempted to be used are not in the grouping. But I'm not sure what the issue is here. The same error appears when I omit QOSdate and ID, except that it is the reference within the `when` clause that becomes the issue.

Comment: try `MIN(QOSdate) OVER()` instead of `MIN(QOSdate)` - note: based on tag and question itself - i assume you use BigQuery. This conflicts with title of question though!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant You're right, title was a mistake - fixed. `OVER()` seems to fix it - thank you!